# Carrot2 FoamTree API

Tags: data-visualization, hierarchical-clustering, voronoi, carrot2

Iam working on Carrot2 FoamTree API especially working on Large Hierarchial clustering and I need to know if there is a way to post the leaf node as a hyperlink that when clicked opens the link in a new window??

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use [FoamTree JavaScript API](http://get.carrotsearch.com/foamtree/latest/api/) to listen to `onGroupClick` or `onGroupSelectionChanged` events and open your URLs when those events occur.